# How to pass a Generic class as a parametr to DbSet<> in derivered from DbContext class? Is it possible without realisation of my generic class?

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-5

I Have a base Glossary class :

```
 public class GlossaryBase<T> 
 {

     public GlossaryBase()
     {
         IsActive = true;
     }

     [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public T ID { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public virtual string Name { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [DefaultValue(true)]
     public Boolean IsActive { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [DefaultValue(0)]
     public int SortOrder { get; set; }


 }
```

then i derivered from it in some other generic class like:

```
public class Navigation<T>:GlossaryBase<T>
{
    [StringLength(100)]
    public override string Name { get; set; }

    public String Controller { get; set; }

    public String Action { get; set; }
}
```

also i have a generic context class like :

```
public class ShopBaseContex
    <TNavigation,//other generic classes> : DbContext
    where TNavigation : class
    //...
{



    public DbSet<TNavigation> Users { get; set; }
    // other Generic set properties...

}
```

from wich i deriver my context like that :

```
public class ShopContext :
    ShopBaseContex
        <Navigation<Int32>, //other generic/nongeneric classes >
{

}
```

So it falls because i pass in generic param in ShopBaseContext a generic class Navigation.
I Dont want to create a realization for each generic class i have. 
example of realization:

```
public class NavigationRealization : Navigation<Int32>
{

}
```

if i pass this class into ShopContext instead of Navigation, it will works perfectly.

So The question is it another way to pass in DbSet<> something like generic Navigation?

Comment: I guess I could help you, but you have to formulate your question better, I cannot make out the actual problem. What is the problem? Why do you have to make "realisations"? What are "realistations"?

Comment: @D.R. Idont want to make realizations iwant to pass the genric Navigation<Int32> insted of NavigationRealization. It falls on enable migrations mapping  with mistake : The type 'IShop.DTO.Models.Navigation`1[System.Int32]' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.

Comment: NavigationRealization just is not the same as Navigation<Int32>. Deriving from a class is not the same as creating an alias (which is unfortunately not possible in C#). You would have to do some reflection magic to get this to work.

Comment: @D.R. NavigationRealization just is not the same as Navigation<Int32>.Deriving from a class is not the same as creating an alias - i know that. I  want to Pass a generic Navigation<Int32> in my context thats all. And i ask: How can i pass it there and enable code first migrations after that?